# Unable to deploy Git repository receiver with flux on gke cluster

Tags: git, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, git-webhooks, fluxcd

I have been getting my hands dirty by setting up a webhook receiver with flux on GKE I followed the insructions of this [guide](https://toolkit.fluxcd.io/guides/webhook-receivers/) . According to it I need to deploy Git repository receiver as shown below :

```
apiVersion: notification.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1beta1
kind: Receiver
metadata:
  name: webapp
  namespace: flux-system
spec:
  type: github
  events:
    - "ping"
    - "push"
  secretRef:
    name: webhook-token
  resources:
    - kind: GitRepository
      name: webapp
```

When i apply the same on gke cluster with k8s version 1.18.12, i get the following error

```
prkumar@cloudshell:~ (portworx-eng)$ kubectl apply -f GitRepository.yml
error: unable to recognize "GitRepository.yml": no matches for kind "Receiver" in version "notification.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1beta1"
```

I tried to check if the CRD's are present but I couldn't find anything :

```
prkumar@cloudshell:~ (portworx-eng)$ kubectl get customresourcedefinitions --all-namespaces
NAME                                                         CREATED AT
actionapprovals.autopilot.libopenstorage.org                 2021-02-15T16:22:04Z
applicationbackups.stork.libopenstorage.org                  2021-02-15T16:22:32Z
applicationbackupschedules.stork.libopenstorage.org          2021-02-15T16:22:47Z
applicationclones.stork.libopenstorage.org                   2021-02-15T16:22:42Z
applicationregistrations.stork.libopenstorage.org            2021-02-15T16:22:27Z
applicationrestores.stork.libopenstorage.org                 2021-02-15T16:22:37Z
autopilotruleobjects.autopilot.libopenstorage.org            2021-02-15T16:21:59Z
autopilotrules.autopilot.libopenstorage.org                  2021-02-15T16:21:59Z
backendconfigs.cloud.google.com                              2021-02-15T15:35:57Z
backuplocations.stork.libopenstorage.org                     2021-02-15T16:22:22Z
clusterdomainsstatuses.stork.libopenstorage.org              2021-02-15T16:22:12Z
clusterdomainupdates.stork.libopenstorage.org                2021-02-15T16:22:17Z
clusterpairs.stork.libopenstorage.org                        2021-02-15T16:21:57Z
frontendconfigs.networking.gke.io                            2021-02-15T15:35:59Z
groupvolumesnapshots.stork.libopenstorage.org                2021-02-15T16:21:51Z
managedcertificates.networking.gke.io                        2021-02-15T15:35:22Z
migrations.stork.libopenstorage.org                          2021-02-15T16:22:02Z
migrationschedules.stork.libopenstorage.org                  2021-02-15T16:22:07Z
rules.stork.libopenstorage.org                               2021-02-15T16:21:31Z
schedulepolicies.stork.libopenstorage.org                    2021-02-15T16:21:36Z
servicenetworkendpointgroups.networking.gke.io               2021-02-15T15:35:59Z
storagestates.migration.k8s.io                               2021-02-15T15:35:26Z
storageversionmigrations.migration.k8s.io                    2021-02-15T15:35:26Z
updateinfos.nodemanagement.gke.io                            2021-02-15T15:35:27Z
volumeplacementstrategies.portworx.io                        2021-02-15T16:20:24Z
volumesnapshotclasses.snapshot.storage.k8s.io                2021-02-15T15:35:25Z
volumesnapshotcontents.snapshot.storage.k8s.io               2021-02-15T15:35:25Z
volumesnapshotdatas.volumesnapshot.external-storage.k8s.io   2021-02-15T16:21:41Z
volumesnapshotrestores.stork.libopenstorage.org              2021-02-15T16:21:46Z
volumesnapshots.snapshot.storage.k8s.io                      2021-02-15T15:35:25Z
volumesnapshots.volumesnapshot.external-storage.k8s.io       2021-02-15T16:21:41Z
volumesnapshotschedules.stork.libopenstorage.org             2021-02-15T16:21:41Z
prkumar@cloudshell:~ (portworx-eng)$
```

Pods

```
prkumar@cloudshell:~ (portworx-eng)$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
demo          podinfo-58df84dbff-4wcl4                                         1/1     Running   0          9h
demo          podinfo-58df84dbff-54rbg                                         1/1     Running   0          9h
flux          flux-86845fff46-p6bdz                                            1/1     Running   0          9h
flux          memcached-5bd7849b84-k4g2h                                       1/1     Running   0          9h
kube-system   autopilot-859d58c8c4-x59b6                                       1/1     Running   0          10h
kube-system   event-exporter-gke-564fb97f9-2l4fp                               2/2     Running   0          10h
kube-system   fluentbit-gke-j42rm                                              2/2     Running   0          10h
kube-system   fluentbit-gke-ngv2c                                              2/2     Running   0          10h
kube-system   fluentbit-gke-zqjk4                                              2/2     Running   0          10h
kube-system   gke-metrics-agent-n7255                                          1/1     Running   0          10h
kube-system   gke-metrics-agent-rbc2b                                          1/1     Running   1          10h
kube-system   gke-metrics-agent-wmndz                                          1/1     Running   0          10h
kube-system   kube-dns-6bd88c9b66-dtn5c                                        4/4     Running   0          10h
kube-system   kube-dns-6bd88c9b66-jkq6w                                        4/4     Running   0          10h
kube-system   kube-dns-autoscaler-7f89fb6b79-6bbn2                             1/1     Running   0          10h
kube-system   kube-proxy-gke-prashanth-cluster-te-default-pool-28f88aed-0jhg   1/1     Running   0          10h
kube-system   kube-proxy-gke-prashanth-cluster-te-default-pool-28f88aed-3k7t   1/1     Running   0          10h
kube-system   kube-proxy-gke-prashanth-cluster-te-default-pool-28f88aed-hrxd   1/1     Running   0          10h
kube-system   l7-default-backend-7fd66b8b88-7h8jj                              1/1     Running   0          10h
```

Any help or advice is most welcome.

-Prashanth

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the flux tool kit which was not installed. Following the documentation from the below link helped me to resolve the issue.
https://github.com/fluxcd/kustomize-controller

Answer (score 0):

Acording to the documentation, your manifest seems to be wrong.

To deploy a Git repository with [Webhook Receivers](https://toolkit.fluxcd.io/guides/webhook-receivers/) you have to bear in mind:

```
In order to receive Git push or Helm chart upload events, you'll have to expose the 
webhook receiver endpoint outside of your Kubernetes cluster on a public address.
```

What the flux documentation suggest you to do is:

1. Create a LoadBalancer service.
2. Assing a public addres to it.
3. Define a Git repostory.
4. Define a Git repository receiver.

You can follow step by step the confugartion of your files in this [link](https://toolkit.fluxcd.io/guides/webhook-receivers/#expose-the-webhook-receiver) of the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did expose cluster with Public address but here the issues seems to be with "no matches for kind "Receiver" " which i doubt is anywhere related to Public address.  When i am defining a  Git repository receiver, seeing the issue.

Comment: If you go to the documentation you can find that they don't set `kind: Receiver`, they set `kind: Service`. Try to follow the examples in the documentation and let me know if it works.

Comment: I was able to add Service but when i go to step Define a Git repository receiver, with the below changes it give me error                                                                     apiVersion: notification.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1beta1
kind: Receiver
metadata:
  name: webapp
  namespace: flux-system
spec:
  type: github

Comment: I got the solution for the same. Flux tool kit was not installed, after following this link https://github.com/fluxcd/kustomize-controller now able to apply the spec.

Comment: Great! Can you post an answer so anyone with similar problem in the community can find the solution as well?